# How to specify Twilio Whatsapp template from the python client?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I would like to use Twilio Whatsapp messages with custom templates. I'm trying to send messages using a Python client. We have different types of messages and we would like to manage them from Twilio backend. We created several templates, but I have no idea how to specify a template in the code.

In the official documentation there is no mention of this. I looked into the source code of the client, here is a code from class MessageList, that I use for message creation:

```
    def create(self, to, status_callback=values.unset, application_sid=values.unset,
           max_price=values.unset, provide_feedback=values.unset,
           attempt=values.unset, validity_period=values.unset,
           force_delivery=values.unset, content_retention=values.unset,
           address_retention=values.unset, smart_encoded=values.unset,
           persistent_action=values.unset, from_=values.unset,
           messaging_service_sid=values.unset, body=values.unset,
           media_url=values.unset):
```

There is nothing similar to the template name in function parameters.

Is it possible at all to specify the template programmatically?

Comment: I am also facing the same thing. Just wondering have you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you want to send a message using a template, all you have to do is ensure that the body of the message you are sending matches the template. For example, if your templates is:

```
Your login code for {{1}} is {{2}}.
```

Then sending the message:

```
Your login code for Twilio is 12345.
```

matches that template and will send successfully. So you don't specify the template programmatically, just with your message content.

You can see more about [sending template messages with the Twilio API for WhatsApp here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates).

Comment: Thank you very much. I already clarified this with Twilio support and wanted to update this entry. But you did it for me.

Comment: Good to hear! Would you mind marking it as correct so that others can see this was the right answer too? Thanks!

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore... are there any characters that invalidates the match against the template?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If you are following this advice and the documentation and it’s still not working, I recommend opening a ticket with support.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client() # this is the Twilio sandbox testing number

from_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:+14155238886'

to_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:+15005550006'
client.messages.create(body='Ahoy,world!', from_=from_whatsapp_number, to=to_whatsapp_number)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. I send messages this way. It works. 


But we would like to specify which template to use for a specific message. 


We have a bunch of templates in Twilio backend. For example we have an event and we would like to notify user about this event with a specific message, stored in Twilio.


In theory I would like to have something like:

```client.messages.create(..., template_name='update_profile')```

Comment: I don´t understand this, where is the reference to the template?